# How to correctly receive camera images from onImageAvailable?

Tags: android, live-streaming, android-camera2

I am trying to achieve video streaming from one android device to another. In order to do this I want to obtain frames from camera, send them through sockets and show on ImageView on another phone. The problem is that I have to use ImageReader with specific format - YUV_420_888. When I try to create bitmap based on bytes from this image I can only get ALPHA_8(other formats cause Exceptions saying that buffer is not big enough for pixels), which is black and white + wrongly oriented. I would like to know if there is a way to obtain correct version directly or somehow convert it so I can make a proper bitmap ready to show on ImageView. Here's some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private ImageReader mImageReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        this.handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                if(msg.what == Worker.PROCESSED_IMAGE)
                {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) msg.obj);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void openCamera()
    {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try
        {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 50);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new Worker(this, this.handler, mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight()), new Handler());

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        }
        catch(CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


public class Worker implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener
{
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader)
    {
        Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

        Image.Plane plane = image.getPlanes()[0];
        ByteBuffer buffer = plane.getBuffer();
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, heigth, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
        image.close();
        handler.obtainMessage(PROCESSED_IMAGE, bm).sendToTarget();

}
```

Comment: for YUV_420_888, you need all three planes of the **image**

Answer (score 2):

Almost correct, try to use this code instead:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
//        Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "image w = %d; h = %d", image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
        Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        buffer.rewind();
        byte[] data = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(data);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
//use your bitmap
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (image != null) {
        image.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The bitmap is not the proper size with this code. It does not fill the screen.

Comment: @Donato "it does not fill the screen" - this doesn't match the current question / answer. Maybe you set wrong size to [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) or this is just UI problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a helper function to convert image into bitmap:

[Preview2.kt@image -> bitmap](https://github.com/stallpool/OpenEyes/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/kotlin/openeyes/drawalive/seven/openeyes/Preview2.kt#L254)

[Preview.kt@yuvToBitmap](https://github.com/stallpool/OpenEyes/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/kotlin/openeyes/drawalive/seven/openeyes/Preview.kt#L82)

```java
    protected fun yuvToBitmapFaster(bytes: ByteArray, w: Int, h: Int): Bitmap {
        if (yuvType == null) {
            yuvType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(bytes.size)
            `in` = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType!!.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)
            rgbaType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(w).setY(h)
            out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType?.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)
        }
        `in`?.copyFrom(bytes)
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic!!.setInput(`in`)
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic!!.forEach(out)
        val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        out?.copyTo(bmp)
        return bmp
    }
```

btw, Google has an example with MLkit to get camera images and process them as: [VisionProcessorBase.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/kotlin/VisionProcessorBase.kt) and [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/android)